# Submit PDF via email with customized Subject and Message

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf

Using Adobe Acrobat Pro XI, I am working on a medical form form notifying our medical team of new patients. Upon completion of the form, I am trying to set it up to use a button to submit the saved PDF form and send it to our medical team in an email (we use MS Outlook across the organization). I've found multiple scripts that get me close to what I'm looking for, but I'm trying to accomplish this task with the following parameters:

Email To: "medical_team@outlook.com"
Subject Line: "Patient Notification Form - [LastName, FirstName Rank]"
Attach as: PDF
Body / Message: "Please find the attached Patient Notification Form for [LastName, FirstName Rank] attached."

Form Field Names:
     - Last Name: Pull from form field "Patient_Last_Name"
     - First Name: Pull from form field "Patient_First_Name"
     - Rank: Pull from form field "Patient_Rank"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on which scripts you already tried and why they failed you?

Comment: My request is actually SLIGHTLY different now. The only difference is instead of rank, the team I am helping build this for wants the Patient's Service (this is for the military) instead of rank.

Comment: Basically they're looking for the following:

Subject: Patient Notification Form - LastName, FirstName (Service)

Message: Please find the attached Patient Notification Form for Lastname, FirstName (Service) attached.

The Field Names are:
LastName = Patient_Last_Name
FirstName = Patient_First_Name
Service = Patient_Service

Comment: The following output worked in terms of generating the email with a subject and body:

var cToAddr = "richard.j.cohen.mil@mail.mil"
var cSubLine = "Form X-1 returned from client"
var cBody = "Thank you for submitting your form.\n" + "Save the filled form attachment for your own records"

this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody});

Comment: Attempting to add the form field data is where the break down occurs. Adobe allows me to save the script and produces no errors, but the button doesn't do anything with the following:

Comment: var cToAddr = "richard.j.cohen.mil@mail.mil"
var cSubLine = "Patient Notification Form: "+this.getField(Patient_Last_Name)+" "+this.getField(Patient_First_Name)+" "+this.getField((Patient_Service)) 
var cBody = "Please find the attached Patient Notification Form - "+this.getField(Patient_Last_Name)+" "+this.getField(Patient_First_Name)+" "+this.getField((Patient_Service))  

this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody});